# In PgAdmin, what does `[...]` refer to in a result set?

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Sometimes my query results include a cell containing the pattern `[...]`. When I export such results, they render as a blank string. However, when I try to filter on them with `where column_b = ''`, there's no match. You can see below the difference between `column_a`, which equals `''`, `column_b`, which has this pattern, and `column_c`, which is `null`.

I can't find any documentation on this. How can I reference such a value?

[image: PgAdmin results]

Comment: FYI the Domain Name registration for the website listed in your profile has expired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an update as of Version 5.5. On the [v5.5 release notes](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/5.5/release_notes_5_5.html), please see:

> [Issue #6427](https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/6427) - Remove leading whitespace and replace it with ‘[…] ‘ in the Query Tool data grid so cells don’t look empty.

You need a community login to access the bug report, but the content is:

> Description
>
> I'm teaching databases and love pgAdmin4. Now there's a small but very annoying user interface issue related to the "Query Tool" user interface ("Results grid"):
>
> When the resultset contains data types a TEXT/VARCHAR: The output grid field of a row line shows only any string part before the newline.
>
> This is "well-behaved" - but very much looks like the column value would be empty ('' or NULL) in case the first text output character is a newline!
>
> To replicate: Use query tool and evaluate this:
>
> `select E'\nSELECT *\nFROM foo;';`
> .
>
> Expected or suggested behaviour: Show e.g. an ellipsis ( ...)!

See also screencap below :)

[image: pgadmin query selecting an empty string and whitespace]